# Filter by percentage criteria

Tags: apex

I want to add filter by percentage wise,

For example if some one select 0%-25% from selection option value, search result will display only record which have that percentage between 0-25.

How can i do that filter any help?

Visual force page

```
    <apex:page controller="Test1" sidebar="false" readOnly="true"  doctype="HTML-5.0">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Test" mode="edit">




    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Result<br/>

<apex:selectList id="roi" size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!test2}" onchange="updatebnk2(this.value)"   >
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="no" itemLabel=" "/>
              <apex:selectOption itemValue="0%-25%" itemLabel="0%-25%"/>
  <apex:selectOption itemValue="25%-50%" itemLabel="25%-50%"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="50%-75%" itemLabel="50%-75%"/>
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="75%-100%" itemLabel="75%-100%"/>
         <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="results" />
 </apex:selectList>
<apex:actionFunction name="updte2" action="{!check2}">
                   <apex:param assignTo="{!test2}" value="val" name="current"/>
  </apex:actionFunction>
        </td>
      </tr>
           </apex:form> 

    </apex:page>
```

Apex Class

```
public with sharing class Test1{

 public Test1() {


    soql = 'select Id,Percentage__c  from Property__c where name != null';


    runQuery();
  }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that you are getting selected value in controller.
You could change your apex code so as to return the data you are interested in.

```
String selectedFilterValue = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('current');
Integer lowerValue = Integer.valueOf(selectedFilterValue.split('%')[0]);
Integer highValue = Integer.valueOf(selectedFilterValue.split(-)[1].split('%')[0]);

soql = 'select Id,Percentage__c  from Property__c where name != null AND Percentage__c >=:lowerValue AND Percentage__c <=:highValue';
```

Now by running this soql you would be able to get data you are interested in.

**Corrections in code:**
Please remove assignTo attribute used in apex:param and update onchange value to updte2 function.

Comment: How can i get that selected value in controller, Can you help me with that?

Comment: Could you please update code snippet provided in question because, it looks like you are using test2 as action method and sometimes as variable which is not possible. Then we would be able to figure out what exactly you are missing.

Comment: check it now, Yes i am using test2 as action command, I have display that select list option on VF page.  I am having difficulty in using that 4 select list option in controller and filter record by that option.

Comment: Updated code, hope this helps.